# How to create a buttons group with one button having dropdown menu?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

How to create a buttons group with one button having dropdown menu? I ask because in this situation the menu appears not under/below the button but at the left page border. If I remove the group-button class(class="btn-group") (I get the standalone button) the dropdown appears correctly? Is there a way how to manage this?

Here is the link to buttons group manual page just to reference to what I mean.
http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#buttonGroups

Comment: Why do you want a buttongroup with just one button?

Comment: There are more buttons but just one is with dropdown menu ...

Comment: Ah, ok. Could you add some code to your question? I just tried it quick and dirty in my actual bootstrap project and it works fine.

Comment: did you ever solve this? I see the same effect, but no amount of reading or rearranging markup seems to solve it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

BOOTSTRAP 4:

[Nested Button Groups](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/button-group/#nesting)

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Button group with nested dropdown">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">1</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">2</button>

  <div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <button id="btnGroupDrop1" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Dropdown
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="btnGroupDrop1">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dropdown link</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dropdown link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

BOOTSTRAP 3:

The right answer for bootstrap 3.0 is here:

[Nested Button Groups](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#btn-groups-nested)

No need to change CSS:

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">1</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">2</button>

  <div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
      Dropdown
      <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Dropdown link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dropdown link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yep, this is the right answer for 3.0, just wrap your dropdown in a child btn-group.

Comment: @peter added a bootstrap 4 section and replaced bootstrap 3 broken link

Answer (score 7):

I add a custom "*group-dropdown*" class to the "*btn-group*" div wrapping my dropdown button. 
In this way, the dropdown's "*dropdown-toggle*" can be overriden by the custom CSS.

Position in the group is handled by *:first-child* and *:last-child*

Here's the hack : http://jsfiddle.net/Dk7sw/6/ (LESS CODE available too at CSS bottom)

**CSS :**

```
/*

Twitter Bootstrap CSS modifications for having dropdown menus in
buttons groups.
Dropdowns menus are well positionned, under their buttons.

LESS code at bottom

Kure2012.

*/
.btn-group.group-dropdown {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-left: -1px;
}
.btn-group.group-dropdown .dropdown-toggle {
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
}
.btn-group.group-dropdown:first-child {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-right: -1px;
}
.btn-group.group-dropdown:first-child .dropdown-toggle {
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 4px;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
}
.btn-group.group-dropdown:first-child .dropdown-toggle.btn-large {
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 6px;
  border-top-left-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 6px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
}
.btn-group.group-dropdown:last-child {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-left: -1px;
}
.btn-group.group-dropdown:last-child .dropdown-toggle {
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}
.btn-group.group-dropdown:last-child .dropdown-toggle.btn-large {
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 6px;
  border-top-right-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 6px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
}

/* And the LESS Code :
.btn-group{
    &.group-dropdown{
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
        margin-left:-1px;
        .dropdown-toggle{
            .border-radius(0);
        }
        &:first-child{
            margin:0px;
            padding:0px;
            margin-right:-1px;
            .dropdown-toggle{
                .border-top-left-radius(4px);
                .border-bottom-left-radius(4px);
                &.btn-large{
                    .border-top-left-radius(6px);
                    .border-bottom-left-radius(6px);
                }
            }                
        }
        &:last-child{
            margin:0px;
            padding:0px;
            margin-left:-1px;
            .dropdown-toggle{
                .border-top-right-radius(4px);
                .border-bottom-right-radius(4px);
                &.btn-large{
                    .border-top-right-radius(6px);
                    .border-bottom-right-radius(6px);
                }
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

**And HTML :**

```
<!--

Custom HTML : add a "group-dropdown" class to the dropdown
"btn-group" div.
The "btn-group" div must wrap the whole button (button+submenu items), as specified in the bootstrap doc. This allows you to put several dropdowns in the same buttons group.

Works whatever their position in the button group is.

-->

<!---
Here starts the button group
-->
<div class="btn-group">
    <!--First dropdown : note the "group-dropdown" property -->
    <div class="btn-group group-dropdown">
        <a class="btn btn-mini dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" title="Filter by">
            <i class="icon icon-filter"></i>
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">All</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">...</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <!-- Classic button -->
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-mini" title="New">
        <i class="icon-plus-sign"></i>
    </a>

    <!-- Classic button -->
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-mini" title="Import">
        <i class="icon-upload"></i>
    </a>

    <!-- Dropdown in the middle of the button group -->
    <div class="btn-group group-dropdown">
        <a class="btn btn-mini dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" title="Export">
            <i class="icon icon-download"></i>
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">.csv file</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">.json file</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">.ods file</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">.xml file</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">.sql file</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <!-- Dropdown at the end of the button group -->
    <div class="btn-group group-dropdown">
        <a class="btn btn-mini dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" title="Another action">
            <i class="icon icon-home"></i>
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Custom menu</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Custom menu</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Custom menu</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Add after bootstrap.css:

```
.btn-group > .dropdown-toggle {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
    border-top-right-radius: 0px;
    margin-right: -1px;
    }
.btn-group > .btn:last-child, .btn-group > .dropdown-toggle:nth-last-child(2) {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px; }
```

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/TpYfc/17

Comment: You might want to add a 1px negative margin to the dropdown-toggle, otherwise you have a double border between buttons:

http://jsfiddle.net/TpYfc/17/

Comment: This is pretty good. Would be nice though to enable multiple dropdowns in 1 group.

Answer (score 1):

This 4-lines solution was the cleanest to me :

```
.btn-group > *:not(:first-child),
.btn-group > *:not(:first-child) .btn {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This was the code from the link above:

```
<style>
.btn-custom-toolbar > .btn-group {
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
}
.btn-custom-toolbar > .btn-group > .btn, .btn-custom-toolbar > .btn-group >             .dropdown-toggle
{
 -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
 border-radius: 0px;
 -moz-border-radius: 0px;
 margin-left: -1px;
}
.btn-custom-toolbar > .btn-group:first-child > .btn:first-child {
 -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
 -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 4px;
 border-top-left-radius: 4px;
 -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 4px;
 -moz-border-radius-topleft: 4px; 
}
.btn-custom-toolbar > .btn-group:last-child > .btn {
 -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
 -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 4px;
 border-top-right-radius: 4px;
 -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 4px;
 -moz-border-radius-topright: 4px; 
}
</style>
 <body style="padding: 30px;"
 <h1>Version with sub btns</h1>
 <div class="btn-toolbar btn-custom-toolbar">
 <div class="btn-group">
 <button class="btn btn-cust-first">Dropdown 1</button>
 <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
 <span class="caret"></span>
 </button>
 <ul class="dropdown-menu">
 <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
 <li class="divider"></li><li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
 </ul>
 </div>
 <div class="btn-group">
 <button class="btn">Button 1</button>
 </div>
 <div class="btn-group">
 <button class="btn">Dropdown 1</button>
 <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
 <span class="caret"></span>
 </button>
 <ul class="dropdown-menu">
 <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
 <li class="divider"></li><li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
 </ul>
 </div>
 <div class="btn-group">
 <button class="btn">Dropdown 3</button>
 <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
 <span class="caret"></span>
 </button>
 <ul class="dropdown-menu">
 <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
 <li class="divider"></li>
 <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
 </ul>
 </div>
 <div class="btn-group">
 <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
 Dropdown 3
 <span class="caret"></span>
 </button>
 <ul class="dropdown-menu">
 <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
 <li class="divider"></li>
 <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
 </ul>
 </div>
 </div>
 </body>
```